# Need Some Information on a Transformer

Tags: transformer, identification

A few years ago I found an old Peavey Standard 260 and I just took it apart for parts. I want to try to use the transformer for something, but don't know anything about it.[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you put a sig Gen into it? Or measure L ratio?

Comment: My guess is that the black wires are the AC input and the red wires are 300 to 600 VAC center tapped. BE CAREFUL!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the full schematic is readily available. A Google search turned up this (the transformer configuration is shown on the bottom right):

(From: http://music-electronics-forum.com/showthread.php?t=36842)
[image: schematic]